# Is it reasonable to have a lock-in time for up-votes and down-votes?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if this is still the case, but I've noticed several times that an up-vote or a down-vote gets locked in (after 5 hours or something). Does the same thing happen with "accept"s as well?

Anyhoo, I fail to see the logic behind this. Many times, I've been convinced prematurely by an answer or misinterpreted an answer so that I vote it the wrong way. I come back 5 hours later only to realize I can't change my opinion of the answer. What's the rationale behind having this lock-in time? Wouldn't it be a lot better to not have it at all?

Not a big issue really, but it would be neater to have "correct" answers at least look like they're popular.

Comment: This has been [heavily discussed on the mother meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=change+vote). (Note, since you have edit power there is a workaround. Just make some minor edit to the post in question and you get a chance to change your vote.)

Comment: Of course adding a minor edit to the post gives it another step towards mandatory community wiki status.

Comment: I will just mention that there's no "lock-in" for accepting an answer - but dmckee's right, this is something to be discussed on the main meta site.

Comment: accepts are not locked, however, you can't accept "too fast" and you can only change accepts once per day.

Comment: Agreed, this is counter-productive and illogical